How can I print the diff of two hdf5 files?
I am following the following documentation: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/man1/h5diff.1.html
I can print the count of differences between two files by following the syntax
h5diff file1 file2 

In my case it is:
h5diff 5864_20240701.h5 5864_20240701.h5

The above produces:
branch/5864_20240701.h5
dataset: </quote> and </quote>
4634 differences found
dataset: </trades> and </trades>
4 differences found

However, when I look at the docs, it says to print the different, to add an -h option, which I try to do:
h5diff 5864_20240701.h5 5864_20240701.h5 -h 

However I run into:
Object </-h> could not be found in <path_to_file/.../5864_20240701.h5>

